# Counting unique values within date range

Tags: excel

I'm looking to count the number of distinct values (machineId's) that fall between a date range.

Start date: B2

End date: C2

machineId: 'Production Data'!E:E

allDates: 'Production Data'!AH:AH

The formula I have right now is =SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF('Production Data'!AH:AH>=B3, IF('Production Data'!AH:AH<C3, 'Production Data'!E:E)), 'Production Data'!E:E)))

which only returns #VALUE!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following array formula:

```
={SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(($B$2<=AH:AH)*(AH:AH<=$C$2),E:E,""),
                   IF(($B$2<=AH:AH)*(AH:AH<=$C$2),E:E,""))>0,1))}
```

[reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-HP010342343.aspx)